# The highest poem

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, pattern

> I am three, often a person, always a digit, and also witout.
>
> George POUST was his name.
>
> Manufactured by Ford between 1972 and 1976.
>
> YMCA was not my first team in my coaching career.
>
> Theory of Analytical Transformations was not the last of my publications.
>
> The diabolical snake ruined all of the local branch.
>
> Delano could in 1948 done it again.
>
> It was supposed to be the first of many, but Guy and David was not acclaimed.

The digits follow the pattern, and will point to the first name... eh... the title of the acclaimed novel.

Who was the author?

Hint:

> A list of all the reds, and the allied tank is the first

Hint 2:

> Song: Johnny Leaves The Cash Talking

Hint 3:

> Looking at hint 2 with «skiing glasses», will be a strong hint.

Hint 4:

> The first line indicates that this is a three layer puzzle, and you need to solve all of them to solve the puzzle

Hint 5:

> ```
> +---------------------------+---------+----------------------------------------+
> |          Person           |  Digit  |                 witout                 |
> +---------------------------+---------+----------------------------------------+
> | ?                         | ?       | ?                                      |
> | ?                         | ?       | ?                                      |
> | ?                         | ?       | ?                                      |
> | ?                         | ?       | ?                                      |
> | ?                         | ?       | ?                                      |
> | Franklin Delano Roosevelt | 5       | Franklin                               |
> | ?                         | ?       | ?                                      |
> | random list of people     | pattern | a structured list hinted by in hint1-3 |
> +---------------------------+---------+----------------------------------------+
> ```

Comment: Is "witout" a typo or deliberate?

Comment: Do I have to answer that?

Comment: OK, I won't edit to fix it then ;-)

Comment: Would [[tag:literature]] (for knowledge specific to literature, such as authors and books) apply here?

Comment: @bobble not really. The answer is the author of a book, but no knowledge of the content of the book is needed...

Comment: My bad not reading the comments sooner...

Comment: I couldn’t succesfully manage to edit a table as a hidden hint no.5 Please improve anyone?

Comment: @Enigma Markdown tables in spoilers are unfortunately not supported and also will never be. I've replaced it with a pure text table

Comment: Is "...eh.." intentional??

Comment: @newQOpenGLWidget maybe more of an indicator that the first name also is the name of the novel